# Numerical integration in Matlab (Simpson's rule)

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, simpsons-rule

A cubic polynomial is given by

$$y=\frac{x^3}{6RL}$$

with $R$ and $L$ being constants. Use Matlab and numerical methods to find $x_l$ so that

$$L=\int^{x_l}_0 \sqrt{1+(y')^2} dx$$

when $R=200$ and $L=170.$ Evaluate all the integrals by using the composite Simpson's rule.

**Attempt**

So if I understand this correctly, we need to use Simpson's rule to evaluate $x_l$ where

$$\int^{x_l}_0 \sqrt{1+(y')^2} dx = \int^{x_l}_0 \sqrt{1+ (\frac{x^2}{2RL})^2} dx= \int^{x_l}_0 \sqrt{1+ (\frac{x^2}{6800})^2} dx = L = 170$$

But I thought the method is used to estimate the integral, not the limits. Here's the code for the composite Simpson's rule:

```
function I = simpsons(f,a,b,n)
if numel(f)>1 % If the input provided is a vector
    n=numel(f)-1; h=(b-a)/n;
    I= h/3*(f(1)+2*sum(f(3:2:end-2))+4*sum(f(2:2:end))+f(end));
else % If the input provided is an anonymous function
    h=(b-a)/n; xi=a:h:b;
    I= h/3*(f(xi(1))+2*sum(f(xi(3:2:end-2)))+4*sum(f(xi(2:2:end)))+f(xi(end)));
end
```

What do I need to enter as the function? And what do I need to enter for $b$ (the last point of the interval, i.e. $x_l$)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Code for the Bisection method:

```
a=0; b=170; tol=0.001;
f = sqrt(1+((x.^2)./68000).^2);

%Simpson's rule
if numel(f)>1
    n=numel(f)-1; h=(b-a)/n;
    I= h/3*(f(1)+2*sum(f(3:2:end-2))+4*sum(f(2:2:end))+f(end));
else
    h=(b-a)/n; xi=a:h:b;
    I= h/3*(f(xi(1))+2*sum(f(xi(3:2:end-2)))+4*sum(f(xi(2:2:end)))+f(xi(end)));
end

f = 170 - I;
%Bisection method
fa=feval(f,a); fb=feval(f,b);
while abs(b-a)>2*tol
    m=(a+b)/2;
    fm=feval(f,m);
    if fa*fm<=0, b=m;
    else a=m; end
end
```

Comment: $2\times 200\times 170=68000$ Typo, I guess. The function to integrate is $\sqrt{1+ (\frac{x^2}{68000})^2}$. You need a trial and error method.

Comment: Thank you. So I need to try different upper bounds for the integral until the estimate is equal to $170$? Is there a way to determine in advance what would be a good range for $x_l$?

Comment: I don't know why but all these $170$'s make me guessing that $x_l$ is also somewhere close to $170$ !!!

Comment: It's usually a good idea with a problem like this (where you need to do some *correction* process, rather than just a direct calculation) to have some rough idea of what the answer should be. With that in mind, notice that your integrand is $\sqrt{1+\left ( \frac{x^2}{2RL} \right )^2}$. You want that to add up to $L$. If you think of $R$ as huge, then your integrand is basically $1$ until $x$ is also pretty huge, so $x_l$ would be $L$. That's too big, so you need to make it smaller, but not drastically smaller, since your integrand is never larger than $\sqrt{5/4}$ (why?)

Comment: So now any technique for solving nonlinear equations such as Newton's method or bisection should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convienience write:
$$
I(x)=170-\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x^2}{68000}\right)^2}\; dx
$$
Put $x_{l}=0$ and $x_{r}=170$. Then $I(x_{l})>0$ and $I(x_{r})<0$, so now you employ the bisection method to find $x_0\in (x_l,x_r)$ such that $I(x_0)=0$ using Simpsons rule to evaluate the integral involved in evaluating $I(x)$ at each step.

Matlab (or rather Gnu-Octave) code for the bisection method:

```
function [rv]=MyMain(Nknots,tol)
  xx=Bisect(@TT,0,170,Nknots,tol)
end


function [rv]=Simp(ff,a,b,N)
%
%  numerical integration of ff from a to b using
%  Simpson's method with N knots (n should be even)
%
  n=2*ceil(N/2); %working number of knots, forced to even 
  nb2=n/2;
  h=(b-a)/n;
  idxE=2:2:n-1;idxO=1:2:n;

  xE=a+idxE*h;xO=a+idxO*h;
  fE=ff(xE);fO=ff(xO);
  rv=(ff(a)+2*sum(fE)+4*sum(fO)+ff(b))*h/3;
end

function [rv]=FF(x)
  rv=sqrt(1+(x.^2/68000).^2);
end

function [rv]=TT(x,N)
  rv=170-Simp(@FF,0,x,N);
end

function [rv]=Bisect(ff,a,b,Nknots,tol)
%
%  ff is the function that you wand the root of
%  the roots is to be in the interval (a,b) as we
%  require that f(a)*f(b)<0, so a and b bracket a root.
%

  while abs(b-a) > tol
    x = (a+b)/2;
    y = ff(x,Nknots);

    if y == 0 
      rv = x;
      break
    end

    if ff(a,Nknots)*y < 0
      b = x;
    else
      a = x;
    end
  end

  rv=(a+b)/2;
end
```

Of course you could use one of the built in root finders if you are allowed.

Running the computation from the command line:

```
>> tic,MyMain(100,1e-12),toc
xx =  167.23
Elapsed time is 0.036 seconds.
>>
>> tic,MyMain(10000,1e-12),toc
xx =  167.23
Elapsed time is 0.0530002 seconds.
>>
>> tic,MyMain(10000,1e-8),toc
xx =  167.23
Elapsed time is 0.033006 seconds.
>>
>> tic,MyMain(100,1e-8),toc
xx =  167.23
Elapsed time is 0.0310061 seconds.
>>
```

Changing from n=100 to n=10000 in Simpson's rule less than doubles the computational time required.

The solution method can be improved somewhat if you send some time analysing the problem. It is quite obvious that the desired root is close to $x=170$, so starting with $0$ as the left hand limit for the bisection can be improved. But really unless you are in a production environment the time spent on further analysis is not really cost effective given how fast this executes as it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. But I'm still having some trouble implementing this form of bisection method in Matlab. I am getting errors that `index must be a positive integer`, so what do I exactly need to do to fix this? I have attached my code to my original post above.

Comment: Thank you, but how do you incorporate the code for Simpson's rule into the code for Bisection method? So that at each midpoint, Simpson's rule calculates a new value for the function. I think this is where my code fails.

Comment: Alternatively, if bisection does not work with Simpson's method, I would appreciate it if you could show me how to exactly incorporate built in root finders (such as _fzero_) into my Simpson's code.

Comment: Bisection does work with Simpson's rule, unfortunately the rest of the code to demonstrate this is on my office computer, which I will not have access to for another 4-5 hours from now.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes. Since the integrand is never less than $1$, you know that $x_l<170$. In fact, when $x=170$, the integrand will be about $1.087$, so the eventual answer is bounded below by $\frac{170}{1.087}=156.5$. That gives you a pretty good idea about the starting point.

Bisection is useful when you don't have the derivative available, but here the you have the derivative in the form of the integrand, so it seems to be simpler to implement Newton's method in this case unless bisection is the point of the assignment.

Also you know the integral up to a point near to the actual root at each step after the first, so you need not integrate all the way from zero to the next guess for the root, just from the previous guess. Even if you integrated from zero every time, this program would zip through pretty fast anyway.

**EDIT**: Newton's method

```
% simp.m

f = @(x) sqrt(1+(x^2/68000)^2);

err = 1;
tol = 1.0e-8;
N = 10000;
a = 0;
b = 163;
while abs(err) > tol,
    h = (b-a)/N;
    y = f(a);
    for i = 1:N/2,
        y = y+4*f((2*i-1)*h)+2*f(2*i*h);
    end
    y = y+4*f(b-h)+f(b);
    y = h/3*y-170;
    yp = f(b);
    err = y/yp;
    b = b-err;
end
b
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this code, I really do appreciate it. It works perfectly.